# I get logged in without entering my credentials

Tags: support, login

Whenever I log in to Stack Overflow using my Gmail account, it logs me on just clicking the Gmail button and does not ask me for my credentials. Why is this so?

I'm not even logged in to my computer. Though I logout every time.

Comment: Are you logged in at google?

Comment: You must be logged in to your google account. That's how OpenId works.

Comment: If you're not logged in to your computer how on earth did you post this question?

Comment: Right now I've been logged in automatically on that gmail button click

Comment: Awesome, isn't?

Comment: My bad! I was logged in my computer. I didn't remember when did I do that. Sorry.

Comment: Maybe some background: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/global-auth-is-dead-long-live-universal-login and its predecessor https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work

Comment: Should I delete this post?

Comment: That is up to you. it is not an awful question but I'm not sure if many users will even notice what you did. Just leave it. It doesn't do any harm so far.